# How can I connect to mysql database which is on the server locally?

Tags: mysql, remote-access, database

I've imported my databases on the server and I want to access them locally. The problem is I cannot. I mean the server doesn't response to my request.

I've added `root` to having access to "mydb" user list and I've given *(granted)* all privileges to it. Also I've commented `bind_address` in `my.conf` file and then I've restarted the mysql.

Still when I run this command:

```
telnet <ip> 3306
```

No response received.

Any idea how can I make a connection between my local and the database on the server?

---

#### MyTests:

- [`sudo netstat -plnt`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtGw5.png)
- [`tcpdump port 3306`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXgd3.png)
- [`sudo netstat -tulnp | grep 3306`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oB6H.png)

Comment: Try this `mysql -u fooUser -p -h <IP_ADD>`

Comment: @George Should I try it from where? In the SSH or the server? Or from my local?

Comment: From local as this was your intention, right?

Comment: Yes it is my intention, and it throws: `ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 2 "No such file or directory"`

Comment: Please add your `IP` to the `bind_address` line in `my.conf` and try again, and open `port 3306` if using firewall on server

Comment: @George The error changed: `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '88.198.86.120' (10061 "Unknown error")`. *(noted that I've added my local ip as the value of `bind_address` and restarted `mysql`)*

Comment: Your sure it's running?

Comment: @George What you mean *"it is running?"*? Can you please take a look at my server if I give you the username and password of the server?

Comment: And how would you do that without others seeing it?

Comment: @George I can do that if you give me your email name, or something similar

Comment: @George Email has been sent.

Comment: Are you suing a firewall on the server

Comment: @George I don't know. maybe

Comment: Please `bind_address` should be `bind-address` please check it and change it accordingly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64312/discussion-between-george-and-stack).

Answer (score 0):

With problems `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '88.198.86.120' (10061 "Unknown error")`. You can grant permission for user root with IP `88.198.86.120(IP locally)` as command:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@'88.198.86.120' IDENTIFIED BY 'NbYe&er9gTdbEzVkcHJbZ$r' with grant option;

mysql> flush privileges;
```

If you running firewall, you should allow IP `88.198.86.120` connect to port `3306` with:

```
ufw allow from 88.198.86.120 to any port 3306
```